# SaltStack base, dev, prod environment setup question

Tags: salt-stack

New to saltstack, I have created a base environment and seems to be working fine. Now I'm trying to setup a dev and prod environment so I can have have custom modules along with also adding some from the base environment.

However even with setting up a dev environment in my master config, all base and dev minions are getting the same modules.

These are the changes made to the salt master config file (etc/salt/master)

File Server setting

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /opt/base/
  dev:
    - /opt/dev/
    - /opt/base/
  prod:
    - /opt/prod/


top_file_merging_strategy: same
```

---

Node Groups

```
nodegroups:
  dev: 'L@rnd301.com,rnd302.com,rnd304.com,rnd305.com'
```

---

Pillar settings

```
pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /opt/pillar
  dev:
    - /opt/dev/pillar
```

---

---

This is the dev **top.sls** config

```
dev:
  '*':
    - pw_new

base:
  '*':
    - sudo
    - sshkeys
```

---

Base top.sls config

```
base:
  '*':
    - common
    - sudo
    - dns
    - ntp
    - repos
    - history
    - rootpw
```

---

When i run the salt-call i see that all the base files hit the dev minion along with base minions.

---

```
      ID: pw_new
Function: user.present
  Result: True
 Comment: User rootpw_new is present and up to date
 Started: 12:39:09.350877
Duration: 4.361 ms
 Changes:
```

### Summary for local

Succeeded: 49

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
  dev:
    - /opt/dev/
    - /opt/base/
```

You told it that the `dev` environment includes everything in `base`. So it merges both `/opt/dev/top.sls` and `/opt/base/top.sls`, and then the `'*'` matches every minion.

Comment: That makes sense 
So what would be best practice on setting up a base, dev and prod environment? 

I want to be able to use some of the base items in different environments.